# Rewrite root folders to a php file and exclude some folders

Tags: htaccess, apache

I want to rewrite all the root folders to `mysite.com/index.php?folder=^folder` using Apache htaccess.
However, I don't want the images folder to be rewritten.
Like Facebook.

Comment: I have found the solution, thank you about your interest w3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Those rules will rewrite all the submits to `index.php?q=variable`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Just to add, if you use a relative path substitution in the `RewriteRule` directive (ie. `index.php`) you should specify a `RewriteBase` directive, otherwise results could be unpredictable on different servers, or break if the code was moved to another folder. Alternatively, specify a root-relative (or absolute) path.